# Angular span color not applied by class?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular application and part of it spits out a piece of text that needs to be colorized dynamically, in order to do that I am injecting a span element where required and marking it with a class, so the output would be something like this:

```
Some text <span class="failResult">that's emphasized</span> and other text too.
```

I am using a td (it's inside a table) that has inner html binding to this value.  The css for this class is very simple.  There are several similar classes that change the appearance a bit based on calculated values, but they all look something like this:

```
.failResult {
  color: #dd2222;
}
```

I'm getting the html showing the text correctly, but the color isn't showing on the portion within the span.

Things I have tried:

- I used dev tools to view the output and the class is applied.  Here is an example of the td as output by the browser: `<td _ngcontent-c4="">17 Checks, 7 <span class="failResult">(61%)</span> Pass, 3 Fail, 5 Count/List, 2 Not Run</td>`
- I verified that the class exists in the css file, is loaded by the browser, and the name is typed correctly.
- I applied the color attribute to the span directly through browser dev tools and it shows up correctly, the color of the text changes.
- I tried setting the color instead of the class in the string value, however Angular sanitizes this for security.  Incidentally it did NOT give me any sanitizing messages about the class.
- I tried applying the other classes via browser dev tools and they also did not change the color.

Is there something I don't know that span will not reflect a color applied via class?  How do you get this to work?

**EDIT**

Doesn't have much to do with this question but for completeness here is the code that generates the contents:

```
 GetReportSummary(): string {
    const values = [];

    values.push(`${this.TotalChecks} Checks`);
    if (this.PassingChecks > 0 || this.FailingChecks > 0) {
      let resultClass = 'passResult';
      if (this.PassPercent < 70) {
        resultClass = 'failResult';
      } else if (this.PassPercent < 90) {
        resultClass = 'warnResult';
      }
      values.push(`${this.PassingChecks} <span class="${resultClass}">(${this.PassPercent}%)</span> Pass`);
      values.push(`${this.FailingChecks} Fail`);
    }

    if (this.ReportingChecks > 0) {
      values.push(`${this.ReportingChecks} Count/List`);
    }

    if (this.NotRunChecks > 0) {
      values.push(`${this.NotRunChecks} Not Run`);
    }

    if (this.ErrorChecks > 0) {
      values.push(`<span class="errorResult">${this.ErrorChecks} Error</span>`);
    }

    return values.join(', ');
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this style based on certain criteria?  Might need some more info about the actual code on this

Comment: The code doesn't have an effect on this (see answer below by @Narm), but for the sake of completeness and in case anyone sees a better way to do this, I updated the question with the code that generates the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to the way Angular uses encapsulation to scope its styles to specific components. If you add the style to your projects main **styles.css** file then it should work.

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely correct... why?  Does it change the class names somehow when compiling?  I did look through sources in dev tools and it shows the original styles in the src file structure but not sure if that's some magic with development mode for Angular...  Would love to know more about how it works for my own education.

Comment: Angular *does not* change the class names. What they do is add scoping attributes to specific elements of individual components (as seen in your `<td _ngcontent-c4 ...`). The addition of the attribute `_ngcontent-c4` scopes all the styles applied in that component strictly to the elements within that component, because the `span` is dynamically added it will not contain the same scoping attribute that the rest of the components elements were assigned. By adding the style to the global styles it negates scoping rules and applies the style to all matching classes.